# Where is the discriminate tactic defined in Coq?

Tags: coq, beginner, reference-request, tactic

One can read the Coq documentation about `discriminate` tactic [here](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proofs/writing-proofs/reasoning-inductives.html#coq:tacn.discriminate).

Were is this tactic actually defined?

Comment: It's a builtin, it seems to be defined [here](https://github.com/coq/coq/blob/master/tactics/equality.ml) at `discr_tac`. See also [here](https://github.com/coq/coq/blob/master/plugins/ltac/extratactics.mlg).

Comment: Thank you! I'm interested in developing a bit more precise understanding of how tactics transform terms in the proof environment. I've seen *some* LTAC and I think it would be interesting to see how tactics operate under the hood.